# as3 video full screen mode

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flv, fullscreen

I have created a video player, but need to add a button that, when clicked, puts the video into full-screen viewing mode. I don't want to scale everything on the stage - just the video. I can't seem to find how to do this - I thought it would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
videoPlayer.x = 0;
videoPlayer.y = 0;
//save the width and height in temp vars 
//for restoring them later.
videoPlayer.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
videoPlayer.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can only set the entire stage to full screen, not elements selectively, as you are effectively scaling up the stage object at the root of the display tree.  The best way to accomplish the effect that you are looking for would be to arrange/hide/show any objects that you don't want to be visible in a FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN event handler.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/FullScreenEvent.html

Also, a relevant tidbit from the Stage docs, [displayState section](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState):

> The scaling behavior of the movie in full-screen mode is determined by the scaleMode setting (set using the Stage.scaleMode property or the SWF file's embed tag settings in the HTML file). If the scaleMode property is set to noScale while the application transitions to full-screen mode, the Stage width and height properties are updated, and the Stage the resize event.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this problem recently and this worked like charm. So putting it up here in case it helps anyone.

Flex Client code:

```
private function startFullScreen(event:MouseEvent):void
{    
    videoHolder.removeChild(vid);  //videoHolder is an spark VideoDisplay  
                                       Component
    this.stage.addChild(vid);           
    this.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    oldWidth = vid.width;         //store old values required while going back
    oldHeight = vid.height;
    vid.width = this.stage.width;
    vid.height = this.stage.height;
    this.stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN,fullScreenHandler);
}
} 


/*      handler for Fullscreen      */
private function fullScreenHandler(event:FullScreenEvent):void
{
    //This function is called when user presses Esc key 
    //on returning to normal state, add the video back  

    if(!event.fullScreen)
    {               
        this.stage.removeChild(vid);
        videoHolder.addChild(vid);
        vid.width = oldWidth;
        vid.height = oldHeight;
        this.stage.removeEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN,fullScreenHandler )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If elements on the stage are scaling it sounds as though you're using the fullScreenRect property rather than simply instructing the stage object to go into fullscreen mode.

Amarghosh has the right approach, but it can be made more flexible by attaching a listener:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, _onStageResize, false, 0, true);
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;

private function _onStageResize(event:Event):void
{
    if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN)
    {
        // Proportionally resize your video to the stage's new dimensions
        // i.e. set its height and width such that the aspect ratio is not distorted
    }
    else
    {
        // Restore the normal layout of your elements
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Enter Full Screen Mode**

```
var fullScreenButton:Button = new Button();
...
addChild(fullScreenButton); 
fullScreenButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreenButtonHandler);
...
private function fullScreenButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent) 
{  
    var screenRectangle:Rectangle = new Rectangle(video.x, video.y, video.width, video.height); 
    stage.fullScreenSourceRect = screenRectangle; 
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;  
}
```

**To Leave Full Screen Mode**

```
...
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
...
```

Note: You can also press escape.

Source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS44B1892B-1668-4a80-8431-6BA0F1947766.html