# Full screen video in the middle of the screen

Tags: actionscript-3, video, fullscreen

After using the answer I found here
[as3 video full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457318/as3-video-full-screen-mode)
which was :

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
videoPlayer.x = 0;
videoPlayer.y = 0;
videoPlayer.width = stage.fullScreenWidth;
videoPlayer.height = stage.fullScreenHeight;
```

My video is full screen size, but anchored in the same point as it was on the stage, putting my video off to the side.

Is there an algorhythm I can use to calculate how many negative pixels I should move my video so it's displaying edge to edge?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done some ActionScript 3 coding, but vaguely remember it could relate to the scale mode of the `Stage`.

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines and your code might work. By default, the stage scales up to fill the screen (VIEW_ALL) and is centered.

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the width of your video and the stage and use the half of it:

when anchor of videoPlayer is topleft:

```
videoPlayer.x = (stage.fullScreenWidth - videoPlayer.width) / 2;
videoPlayer.y = (stage.fullScreenHeight- videoPlayer.height ) / 2;
```

when anchor of videoPlayer is centered:

```
videoPlayer.x = stage.fullScreenWidth / 2;
videoPlayer.y = stage.fullScreenHeight / 2;
```

**Edit:** after reading your question again, you can try to relocate your video after resizing:

```
import flash.display.StageAlign;

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, myResizeHandler);

private function myResizeHandler(event:Event) {
    videoPlayer.x = 0;
    videoPlayer.y = 0;
}
```